# How to copy tgz file one server to another linux server in php?

Tags: php, linux

I have one file `example.tgz` hosted in one linux server and I want to copy this file (`example.tgz`) to another linux server.

How can we copy `example.tgz` file from one server to another server please suggest.

Comment: Using http or something else?

Comment: I  want to do it programitilly.

Comment: You need to choose transferring protocol first.

Comment: You could try [copy](http://php.net/copy).

Comment: Okay but how can be transfer this file to another server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code:

```
 <?php
  $connection = ssh2_connect('otherserver.com', 22);
  ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

  ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/example.tgz', '/remote/example.tgz', 0644);
 ?>
```

Please run this code from local, it copy example.tgz files into /remote/ folder.